# I'm comparing two variables in an IF statement but I'm getting wrong results

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this code and when running for the first time i clicked **start** and i got me the result "1 is smaller than 2" whick is right but after changing the first input to 10 and clicking **start** again, it still showed "10 is smaller than 2". Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<textarea type="number" id="one">1</textarea>
<textarea type="number" id="two">2</textarea>

<a href="#" onclick="start()">Start</a>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function start() {
    var numberOne = document.getElementById('one').value;
    var numberTwo = document.getElementById('two').value;
    
    if(numberOne>=numberTwo) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = numberOne + ' is bigger than ' + numberTwo;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = numberOne + ' is smaller than ' + numberTwo;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: hey, this is because the variable is being stored as a string, not a numeric variable, thus it is messed up, i am sending the full code in a minute

Comment: `<textarea>` doesn’t have `type="number"`. If you meant `<input>` instead, then use `document.getElementById("one").valueAsNumber <= document.getElementById("two").valueAsNumber`. Otherwise, use `Number` to convert both strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings, not numbers.

use parseInt or parseFloat to convert it to a number.

```js
var numberOne = parseFloat(document.getElementById('one').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is expected, input in DOM always string even if the type is number.

parse them to number first before comparing.

```js
const intOne = parseInt(numberOne, 10);
const intTwo = parseInt(numberTwo, 10);


// compare them
if (intOne >= intTwo) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Edit: Update code by @Sebastian Simon suggestion

Comment: Please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead, or, specifically for `<input>`s, [`.valueAsNumber`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties).